# Storing Strings in c(segmentation fault)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings

Why does this program throw a segmentation fault?. The functions work well individually, but I don't understand why I get the error when I try to store the strings in an array. I need to store all the possible palindromes in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isPal(char s[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(s[j]) {
        j++;
    }
    j--;
    while(i <= j) {
        if(s[i] != s[j]) {
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return 1;
}

char *substring(char s[], int start, int length)
{
    int i, k = 0;
    int end;
    char *p;
    end = start + length - 1;
    p = (char *)malloc(length);
    for(i = start; i <= end; i++ ) {
        p[k] = s[i];
        k++;
    }
    p[k] = 0;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "madamsalayalaspongo";
    char *p[20];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s) - 1; i++) {
        j = 2;
        while(s[j]) {
            if(isPal(substring(s, i, j)));
            {
                p[k] = substring(s, i, j);
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < (k - 1); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I see is

```
  for(i=0;i<strlen(s)-1;i++)
  {
    j = 2;
    while(s[j])
    {
      if(isPal(substring(s,i,j)));
      {

    p[k] = substring(s,i,j);
    k++;
      }
      j++;
    }
  }
```

Here you are initializing j = 2 with every iteration of i. Then you go on and extract the substring with i as starting index and j as length. And your inner loop continues till s[j] becomes 0 i.e end of string. Now with any value of i > 0 (i.e from 1 onwards), and j = "strlen(s) - 1" (i.e last character of string), your substring function will result in "Array out of bound" and it can lead to segmentation fault. I think you should initialize j to "i + 1"

Comment: Tried.But the problem still persists.Please note that i am checking for all substrings starting from length 2 onwards.

Comment: It helps if you can run debugger and see where it is segfaulting

Comment: You missed to point the `;` after `if(isPal(substring(s,i,j)))`
Also this is not the only problem

Answer (score 0):

Many problems see fixes below :
(assuming you're finding all palindrome from a given string)

In `substring`

allocate `p` as

`p = (char *)malloc(end+2);`

In `main`

`if(isPal(substring(s,i,j))) ;`  // remove the semi-colon

allocated memory for `p[k]`

and use `strcpy` or `strncpy`

May be

```
p[k] = (char *)malloc( (strlen(substring(s,i,j))+1)  * sizeof(char));
strcpy(p[k],  substring(s,i,j));
```

Also, its better to first collect the substring, to avoid several calls.

Comment: Why is there a need for resetting i to 0 in isPal. It is local non-static variable.

Comment: @mshriv oops, sorry I got confused which something else, updated

Comment: @POW why is there a need to allocate memory again for p[k]?.Wont the allocation in the function suffice?.

Answer (score 0):

You get a redundant semicolon here:

```
while(s[j]) {
        if(isPal(substring(s, i, j)));//---------Notice!
        {
            p[k] = substring(s, i, j);
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

Also, the length of a string is not include the `\0`, so `malloc(length + 1)`.

Comment: Correct but this is not the only problem , and this won't cause segfault

Comment: @P0W Have you tried it? This is the cause of the segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not, even if it is, other areas in code will still cause segfault.

Comment: @P0W Yeah, some other errors. But not the cause of segfault, you can try it, fixing that semicolon bug will make it run.

Comment: @arvindlm Great! But this algorithms for finding palindromic substring is sort of inefficient, google some other algorithms that can run in `O(N^2)`